# NextJS getting 500 Error after hosting on Google Cloud

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I've developed web application on NextJs. On local it's all working fine and generated Build folder as well. But when I deploy the build files to Google cloud, I'm getting 500 error. I guess there might be some app.yaml config issue.

I tried lot on this issue, but didn't get much. Please do suggest me what's wrong with my config. Below are the screenshot for your references:

**Build folder structure generated by Nextjs :**

[image]

**app.yaml config**

```
runtime: nodejs16 # or another supported version
instance_class: B1
service: nextjs
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

**GCP Error log**
[image]

Please do suggest what I'm missing here. Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't share screenshots, format your post with an error log. Also share the package.json file and check with this [Github Link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12474#discussioncomment-638821).

Comment: Have you managed to check the link? Also edit question by adding `package.json`